# Vue: $emit is changing parent value, but the v-if is not responding

Tags: vue.js, emit

My code is something like this:

```
//- Parent

ConditionalComponent(v-if="condOne")
MenuComponent(v-if="condTwo", @method="parentMethod")

...
data() {
  return {
   condOne: false
   condTwo: false
  }
},
methods: {
  parentMethod() {
   this.condOne = !this.condOne
   this.condTwo = !this.condTwo
  }
}
```

Values of condOne and condTwo **are changing properly**, but the rendering status of ConditionalComponent and of MenuComponent is not changing, as if the v-if was not working. I don't understand why.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your question is hard to answer because there is no template available to look at. Your mockup of the issue may be hiding what is actually stopping the v-if from functioning.

Comment: @JakeHamTexas Thank you for your willingness to help. If you colud take a look, this is the parent: [link](https://github.com/BrujaVudu/ellas-vue/blob/menu_emit_v-if/src/App.vue) and this one is the component [link](https://github.com/BrujaVudu/ellas-vue/blob/menu_emit_v-if/src/components/Menu.vue) In line 10 of App.vue, the component Menu has the v-if that is modified by the "muestra" method, activated inside the component (lines 14 and 15, method on line 50)

Answer (score 0):

v-if manipulates dom, while v-show use display:none attribute.
Can you try with v-show directive?